# How do I get the data of the URLRequest from the Complete Event handler for a URLLoader in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, url

I have a queue of messages that I would like to send to a URL and I would like to remove messages from that queue only after I am sure they have been successfully sent.  To do this I need to know in the `COMPLETE` event for the `URLLoader` exactly what data was sent so that I can remove the correct message from the queue.

That is if I have something like this.

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(targetUrl);  
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();  
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;  
urlRequest.data = "test";  

urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;  
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);  
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

And then my handleComplete function is like this:

```
public function handleComplete(e:Event):void{  

   //How do I trace the urlRequest.data for this event, whats below does not work.  
   //Because the target of the event is the URLLoader, not the URLRequest.  

   trace(e.target.data);  
}
```

Comment: Are you sending this to a php script? cause then i know the answer.

Comment: It would be to a server side script, it would probably be pearl, but php would work too.

Comment: also call targetUrl in a browser and make sure it is not returning an error

Comment: trace(urlLoader.data); doesn't work, urlLoader.data just gets traced as "undefined" when I try it.  The targetURL is working and the messages I am sending are being logged on my server with a php script.  I just don't know how to verify client side in my AS3 code that they have been received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question of how to get the `URLRequest` object you can simply create your own custom `URLLoader` class that stores the `URLRequest` object. The following is an example of this:

CustomURLLoader.as:

```
package
{
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class CustomURLLoader extends URLLoader
    {
        private var _urlRequest:URLRequest;

        public function get urlRequest():URLRequest
        {
            return _urlRequest;

        }// end function

        public function CustomURLLoader(urlRequest:URLRequest)
        {
            super(urlRequest);
            _urlRequest = urlRequest;

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Main.as(document class):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            if(stage) init()
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        public function init(e:Event = null):void
        {
            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("file.php");
            urlRequest.data = "test"; 
            urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;  
            var customURLLoader:CustomURLLoader = new CustomURLLoader(urlRequest);
            customURLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCustomURLLoaderComplete);

        }// end function

        private function onCustomURLLoaderComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            var customURLLoader:CustomURLLoader = e.target as CustomURLLoader;
            trace(customURLLoader.urlRequest.data); // output: test

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Comment: Awesome, this makes total sense and seems like it should work.  I will try it out first thing tomorrow :).  Thanks!

Comment: Tried it and it worked like a charm :)  Thanks, I marked as answer.